# API call limited results - how to make it show all the results?

Tags: python, app-store-connect

I've been trying to make an API call to get all the users from an Apple Store.
After using this script I only get a limited number of results:

```
import json
from appstoreconnectapi import AppStoreConnect



ISSUER_ID = "..."
KEY_ID = "..."

asc = AppStoreConnect(KEY_ID, "./key.p8", ISSUER_ID)

res = asc.fetch(uri='/v1/users', method='get', post_data=None)
print (res)

with open('output.json', 'w') as out:
    out.write(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
```

After 50 result showed this is what i get at the end of my JSON file:

```
"meta": {
        "paging": {
            "total": 356,
            "limit": 50
        }
    }
```

Comment: Those appear to be paginated results, you'll have to review the docs for the api you're using for specifics but you likely need to send multiple requests with an incrementing `page` parameter to get the next 50 results till you've got them all. Something like `uri='/v1/users?page=2'` then `uri='/v1/users?page=3'` etc....  till you have all 356 results, or possibly there is a parameter to increase the limit like `uri='/v1/users?limit=1000'`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You're also overwritting your file.  Try using the ```a``` mode.

Comment: @ewong what do you mean by **a mode** ? I tried with the limit parameter, but it only goes to 200, that's the max limit i can use.